# Is it pythonic to send form data as pandas dataframe to database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, fastapi

So what I do is:

1. Get form data with fastapi's `python-multipart`
2. Convert the form data to a dictionary
3. Convert the dictionary to a pandas dataframe
4. Send the pandas dataframe to my sqlite database

However, is this the way to do it or is there a better, more pythonic way?

```
from fastapi import Form, Request
import pandas as pd
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

@app.post("/form")
def form_post(request: Request,
              criteria1: str = Form(...),
              criteria2: int = Form(...)):
    result_dict = {"criteria1": criteria1,
                   "criteria2": criteria2
                  }
    df = pd.DataFrame([result_dict])
    df.to_sql("form_result", con="sqlite:///./app.db")
    return templates.TemplateResponse("form.html", context={'request': request})
```

Comment: I don't think this is really a question about "pythonic" or not.  Personally I would be wary there might be type-casting issues converting from dict -> dataframe -> database; if it works (and is performant), maybe I'll steal it though :)

Comment: Haha no problem, I should take that into consideration. And I'd be able to actually specify the data types and I should really before sending it to the DB. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The rule is if it works just leave it but if you are still looking for a better approach then please have a look at this [article](https://python-adv-web-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flask_db3.html).
https://python-adv-web-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flask_db3.html

Comment: Thank you, will this hold for `fastapi` as well, as I'm using that framework?